# Tron API works not as described in documentation

Tags: tron

After I run fresh Tron node with the command

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 --rm --name tron trontools/quickstart
```

I'm trying to get blocks:

```
curl -X POST  http://127.0.0.1:9090/wallet/getblockbylimitnext -d '{"startNum": 1, "endNum": 2}'
```

But instead of an array, the response contains an empty object:

```
{}
```

How to make node to work as it described in documentation here: https://tronprotocol.github.io/documentation-en/api/http/?

Comment: Do you have any transactions in the blockchain? From the response looks like it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a GET request. A corresponding pull request to the docs is created.